# Why "const" is needed here: VS C2664

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constants, msdn

I copy code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

It says that "In Visual C++ 2005, the compiler now enforces the C++ standard requirements for applying const. The following sample generates C2664."

```
// C2664d.cpp
// C2664 expected
#include <windows.h>

void func1(LPCSTR &s)
{

}

void func2(LPSTR &s)
{
   func1(s);
}

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Why do I need to use "const" here?

Comment: Did you try compiling it?  Did you get the error?  Where exactly did you get the error?  What exactly did it say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Those `LPCSTR`/`LPSTR` typenames only obfuscate the code. )

The issue you have here can be expressed in the following succinct way

```
char *p = NULL;
const char *&r = p; // ERROR
```

This code does not compile for the very same reason your original version does not compile: such reference initialization is illegal in C++. In your example the same initialization is used implicitly in function parameter initialization (when calling `func1` from `func2`), while in my example it is done explicitly.

The reason it is illegal is pretty much the same the `T**` -> `const T**` conversion is illegal in C++ (and in C). This is an old FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17.

Basically, if the initialization in my above example were legal, one would be able to continue with the following sequence of operations

```
const char cc = 0;
r = &cc; // OK. Note: `p` now points to `cc`!
*p = 1; // !!! Attempts to modify `cc` !!!
```

meaning that it would allow us to break the const-correctness rules without any "hacks", i.e. without using a single cast. This is considered unacceptable in C++ (as well as in C), which is the reason conversions like `T **` -> `const T **` and initializations like `T *&` -> `const T *&` are not allowed.

Note also, that just like `T**` -> `const T* const*` conversion is legal in C++ (see the FAQ entry), the `T**` -> `const T* const&` initialization is legal as well

```
char *p = 0;
const char *const &r = p; // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

In that code sample, C2664 will be generated because the code is attempting to convert a reference to a pointer into a reference to a const pointer.  Which are two different things.

Converting to a const reference to a pointer (const LPSTR&) would be allowed.

Comment: `LPCSTR` is a typedef for `const char*`, not a `char* const`. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by "reference to a const pointer"?

Answer (score 1):

LPCSTR is defined as "typedef CONST CHAR *LPCST" and 
LPSTR is defined as "typedef CHAR *LPCST"

As you can see, LPCSTR is const and LPSTR is not, so the two types are different and hence you need const in your context.